# How to fix ```ValueError: Trailing data``` during ```pandas.read_json(...)```?

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to read a JSON file into a Pandas dataframe, in the following:

```
def read_JSON_into_dataframe( file_name ):
    with sys.stdin if file_name is None else open( file_name, "r", encoding='utf8', errors='ignore' ) as reader:
        df = pd.read_json( reader )
        print( df.describe(), file = sys.stderr )
        return df
```

However, I'm getting an error, for which to bottom stack frame is:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\json.py in _parse_no_numpy(self)
    869         if orient == "columns":
    870             self.obj = DataFrame(
--> 871                 loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None)
    872         elif orient == "split":
    873             decoded = {str(k): v for k, v in compat.iteritems(

ValueError: Trailing data
```

What does "trailing data" refer to?  If it refers to some point in the JSON file, is there something I can do to figure out where that is and what's wrong with it?

Comment: use a json validator? https://duckduckgo.com/?q=json+validator&atb=v168-1&ia=answer

Answer (score 34):

df = pd.read_json ("filename.json", lines = True)

Comment: You should provide more information about this solution.

Comment: for my case i was trying to read a Json Per line file and df = pd.read_json ("filename.json", lines = True) solved the issue

Comment: Setting `lines=True` reads the file as a json object per line, see [documentation for `pandas.read_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html).

Answer (score 2):

I made such experiment:

- Took a properly formatted JSON file.
- Opened it with a text editor and added " xxxx" after the final "}".
- Attempted to read it, calling *data = json.load(...)*.

The full error message was:

```
JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 112 column 3 (char 6124)
```

So as you can see, you have precisely indicated in which row / column
there was found this extra text.

Take a look at this place of your input file.
Probably it is corrupted in some way, e.g. some "{" char was
deleted.

To find the source of problem you can even use *Notepad++*.
Note that if you place the cursor either before of after a "{" then
this char and also the closing "}" are displayed in red.
The same pertains to "[" and "]".

So this way you can locate matching opening / closing braces or brackets
and find out what is missing.

Of course, usage of *json.load* is not likely to read your file
as a DataFrame, but at least it precisely indicates the place
where the problem occurred.
After you find the source of error and correct it, use your program again.

Comment: Using a JSON validator (https://jsonlint.com/) I found that the JSON was, indeed, broken several ways, but they were easily fixed in ```emacs```.   Once I did that, the ```read_json``` works.